Photon Mass Regulator in IR divergences
On Schwartz's QFT page 333, he metions that there is infrared divergence when we try to renormalized the two-point function of electron field in on-shell substraction scheme,
$$\frac{d}{d\,p_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}}\Sigma(p^{\mu}\gamma_{\mu} = m_P) = \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2}+\frac{5}{4}-\int_{0}^{1}dx\frac{2x(2-x)}{1-x}\right).\tag{18.46}$$
He sequesters the IR divergence by pretending the photon has a tiny mass $m_{\gamma}$.
To me, there is big difference between massive and massless particles. For example, we know that the little groups associated to massive particles and massless particles are different, how can we assume that the photon has tiny mass and then take it to $0$?
Is it something like, first we assume photon is massive spin 1 particle with $2+1 = 3$ DOFs, and in the limit of zero mass, the additional DOF would vanish?

The current experimental limits on the photon mass are on the order of 1e-16eV. By how much does this change the quantities that you are trying to calculate?

Well, I would say there are many different views on this particular technique in order to split-off IR-divergencies. If you take the "photon-mass"-regularization literally then you could introduce it via a Stückelberg-like mechanism. And then think about the limit $m_\gamma \to 0$ in this setup (Which as far as I know actually works at least in QED).
Another view would be to take it just as another regularization method. Which enables you to study the occurrence and cancellation of soft and collinear divergencies and the construction of observables that are free of them. Actually I haven't seen a "modern" calculation that involved photon mass regularization in cases where the "QED-like" corrections could not be factorized from the other corrections in a gauge-invariant way.
It is up to you if you want to study "view 1" or accept "view 2".
